# How to Remote Authentication to SharePoint Online using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, authentication

I am trying to
         "Remote Authentication to SharePoint Online using Javascript" 
as given in the following [link](http://woodoweb.com/remote-authentication-to-sharepoint-online-using-javascript/)

But have not been able to successfully authenticate against SP Online. Getting error in the login function.

Comment: Please add a error message. Maybe also add a traffic capture using IE dev tools. What are your parameters the site references you had used (site name, user, did you replace the pwd)? Where is your JS code running/stored (local/sharepoint)?

Comment: I have verified web services url, user and pwd by manually logging in to the server. The JS code is running locally on Visual Studio.